# Does "prescriptive" have solely a negative sense in some communities?

Tags: meaning, offensive-language

**Motivation:** I recently used this phrase:

> (1) people who read English prescriptive grammar books

I was aware from personal experience that a significant number of people (maybe not a majority, but enough to notice a pattern) have, in the context of linguistics and related language disciplines, associated the terms *prescriptive/ist/ism* with negative opinions.

For this reason, I would have preferred to avoid this term, but it really was the most accurate and apt for my intended meaning. Someone had asked what they *should* do with language, and I wanted to tell them what I thought the consensus on this matter was among people who, as a profession or hobby, give advice on how people should use language. To me, this information is contained in prescriptive grammar books (and places like EL&U, of course). I do not know what else or better to call them. Some other words that come to mind are less accurate to me (and *not synonymous*): *traditional grammar books*, *grammar books*, *popular grammar books*. And another option is I think almost surely offensive: *"correct grammar" books*.

So I went with (1), thinking that my neutral content and tone would not suggest any negative intent, but some people were highly offended and accused me repeatedly of meaning something negative despite my insisting multiple times to *not* mean anything negative.

**Question:** Was this a fluke, or is there a context or community where these terms are always offensive by default? I understand that, if I said "She is smart for a prescriptivist", I would be taken by most competent speakers to be implying something negative about prescriptivists. I am not asking about such cases. I am asking about cases like (1) that might reasonably be defended as neutral or even positive, depending on context.

Secondarily, is there another term in common use that I could use instead, to avoid potential problems?

[Wiktionary lists no derogatory sense of *prescriptivist*.](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prescriptivist) [Dictionary.com lists no derogatory sense of *prescriptivist*.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/prescriptivist) COED has no entry specifically for *prescriptivist* (nor do most other dictionaries I checked) but [lists no derogatory sense for *prescriptive*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/prescriptive?view=uk). COED notes that *prescriptive* is often contrasted with *descriptive*, as I was intending it. OED lists no derogatory sense for any of these, but some of the quotes used have a negative tone. So if it is automatically taken as offensive by some, I presume it is a very new development or confined to a small community or special context. And I imagine that you guys are the ones that would know.

Comment: I think "prescriptive" often coincides with "pedantic"--those who impose excessive rules on something.

Comment: This is a question susceptible to a long discussion rather than a concise answer. For a sensible and well-informed account of prescriptive and descriptive approaches to language, see Chapter 1 of 'The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language', freely available here: http://www.cambridge.org/assets/linguistics/cgel/chap1.pdf

Comment: This is good for a meta discussion, but not particularly constructive on main.

Comment: The word itself is not pejorative. I can be used, like any word can, in a pointed manner, like 'Democratic', or 'incoherent', or 'tall'. It's companion, 'descriptivist', can be used in an identical manner.

Comment: @BarrieEngland: I am not asking if it *should* be considered derogatory. I am asking if it *is* derogatory. That is precisely asking for a definite, factual answer rather than a discussion, just like every other question here asking whether or not some term is offensive. I am also aware of the history and am not asking about it.

Comment: @Mitch: I don't understand why it is not constructive. I am asking whether or not people always consider this term derogatory, and I specifically want to know if it's treated this way by the people reading this question. I thought the backgrond was also relevant, but please remove it if not.

Comment: Not constructive because if people are offended, then by definition it is offensive. That leaves only the question of whether they should be.

Comment: @RoaringFish: But *I do not know* whether or not a whole group finds it offensive. That is exactly my question. I have evidence that *one* person here finds it so offensive that they can't consider any other meanings. I want to know if this is also true for other people.

Comment: How many links to linguists knocking prescriptivism do I need to provide?

Comment: It is non constructive because it calls for a long discussion. A fascinating discussion I'd like to have, just not appropriate here in ELU answers or comments. Chat would be better. Visit and ping me.

Comment: @Rachel: short answer - prescriptive (and descriptive) is not pejorative at all ('pejorative' describes the word, not the concept). 'papist' is pejorative; 'Roman Catholic' is not. The negative context that you hear 'prescriptivism' in is that the rules it wants everybody to follow are often made up; the negative context for 'descriptivism' is that it allows 'anything goes'. An exercise for the reader is the positive contexts for both.

Comment: @Mitch: Thank you for answering my question regarding observed usage (in your short answer). That is what I want to know.

Comment: This is a question about the culture of English.SE, framed as a question about the meaning of "prescriptive". The question is unconstructive: "this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion". However it would be a great question on [meta]. Suggest it be migrated there.

Comment: @Mitch ~ you are effectively saying that the word is not pejorative, only the meaning is. You can't split the orthographic/phonological word from its meaning like that.

Comment: @RoaringFish No, Mitch (if I may be so bold) is saying that a word can be used sarcastically. That is completely different from saying that a word holds an innate derogative meaning. If I attack an argument sarcastically by describing the person as a *programmer*, the sarcasm does not arise from a derogatory meaning of *programmer*. It arises from context.

Comment: @ΜετάEd: Yes, that is what I am saying.

Comment: Which is why the first sentence in my answer includes "...you are referring to something that is contextual." Even in sarcasm though, for it to be understood I would have to 'know' the derogatory meaning of the word that you were referring to. No word, btw, has innate meaning. Meaning comes from several sources, but none of them are innate.

Comment: @RoaringFish: There surely are difficulties with what I claim (distinguishing concept and word). I think of it like taboo, for one concept some words are vulgar and others are not ('shit' vs 'feces').  But as to content, 'prescriptivist' is not always used with contempt. Grammar books -are- prescriptive, they are telling you what you -should- say. Is that a bad thing? If you think it is always a bad thing, then that is at variance with how most people use the word 'should' and 'prescriptive'. So then you must also take 'descriptivist' to be pejorative too, because some people use it that way.

Comment: @RoaringFish If I make a sarcastic comment about programmers, you do not have to know a "derogative" meaning of programmers in order to understand the comment. You merely have to get that I have no respect or love of programmers. What you are saying, essentially, is that the sentence "I despise programmers" imposes a new, derogatory meaning on the word "programmers". No. The hearer gets the derogation, to be sure, but doesn't have to associate "hateful" with "programmers" to do so. At best, the hearer associates "hateful" with **me**.

Comment: Rachel, I am proud to be a prescriptivist. I think, especially when teaching children and non-native speakers, there have to be set rules taught before these learners can advance to the things that break the rules. I didn't ever think of myself as a prescriptivist, but have been called that on this site. And I realize I am fine with that.

Comment: @Mitch ~ Rachel's original comments where about *people*, not books, including prescriptive grammarians, writers, editors, and English majors. Books is largely a red herring. How prescriptive a grammar book is depends who it is written for. Low levels need prescriptive. By the time you get post-grad there are no more straight answers.

Comment: @ΜετάEd ~ if I fail to understand your derogatory reference, then I miss the sarcasm. It does happen, but you have to agree that it is a breakdown in communication. "I despise programmers" is not imposing a derogatory meaning on programmers because it says nothing about programmers, only about your opinion of them. "Look at this email - it must have been written by a programmer" would require me to 'know' your derogatory reference to programmer writing skills, and possibly more importantly - to agree with it.

Comment: @RoaringFish For me to understand your example sentence, I would have to know, not what you mean by the word "programmers", but how much (or how little) you esteem programmers. If I miss the meaning, it's not because I failed to know the meaning of "programmers" but because I failed to pick up on your contempt for them.

Comment: So this is now getting auto flagged for comment overflow. I see that some of the people here are chat regulars and in fact in our [main room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/english-language-usage) right now; perhaps all the others can join them there, too.

Comment: @RoaringFish: "people who read English prescriptive grammar books" - you're reading quite a bit of emotion into this. She calls the books prescriptive (not pejoratively), and refer to people who read them (who are presumably not stained immediately by reading these non-disparaged books. You are the one reading dismissal in to it.

Comment: @ΜετάEd: If people are going to argue *instead of answering my intended question*, which is a question of observable fact capable of getting definitive answers (I am asking what people know and observe about the meaning of a term), then I guess it should be closed. But I find this disappointing because the dictionary is no help, so I otherwise don't know if I am inadvertently offending a large group of people (or just a few). I am not asking for whys or justifications. I just want a yes-or-no type answer to my yes-or-no type question: is it usually offensive?

Comment: @Mitch ~ she mentions writers, editors, and English majors too, in a comment if I remember correctly, and who writes prescriptive grammar books if not those pesky prescriptive grammarians?

Comment: @RoaringFish: OK what's the deal? Do you like prescriptivism or descriptivism? Are you annoyed because you -are- one or because someone -called- you one? Or called -someone else- one? This whole thread seems to be about only that. Can we take this to chat?

Comment: @Rachel Then your question should be closed general reference. A good dictionary would have documented *prescriptive* as offensive if it were. That has nothing at all to do either with whether someone would be offended by being labeled prescriptive, or whether someone could use *proscriptive* in a derogatory way. One might do the same with *humanitarian*.

Comment: @Mitch ~ I would say around 80% descriptive, 20% prescriptive. That 20% is because I don't accept that something becomes 'correct' if enough people do it. There has to be reason and logic behind it too. Language, believe it or not, is not random.

Comment: @ΜετάEd: You sunuva... how dare you! some of my best friends are hu... those kind of people.

Comment: I'm disappointed that this community is apparently incapable of answering a simple question factually. :/ I hope this can be reopened; @Rachel, I would suggest deleting *all* the background information, since it seems to be what has led people to defend their beliefs instead of answering the question.

Comment: Rachel, why did you say "prescriptive" as all in your sentence?  Why didn’t you just call them "English grammar books"?

Comment: @tchrist: because I thought it would include books that I wanted to exclude, so for specificity. In the context, theoretical linguistics books and descriptive grammar books would also have reasonably come to mind as *grammar books*, and I wanted to clearly exclude them because what I was saying did not apply to them. I didn't think to say "English non-theoretical-linguistics non-descriptive grammar books", but I don't think it conveys my meaning anyway. Plus, I find it ridiculous and likely no less offensive.

Comment: This question is so meta. :)

Answer (score 7):

Normative instruction in things like grammar, spelling, punctuation, and syntax accomplish several goals that further educational needs by standardizing on (usually written) language.

When your child says, “Mommy, I taked out the trash already,” you naturally correct her usage to the standard *took out the trash*. This helps her function in a society that relies upon standard English for communication.  You are being prescriptive in your usage. You do this for reasons not so different from  a publishing house who has a formal, written style-guide to help its editors and authors provide consistency in their treatment of English.

But what you are doing, what the publishing house is doing, is not linguistics.  You are establishing a normative standard.  Linguistics is about describing how language works; it makes no sense to talk about “prescriptive linguistics”.

That doesn’t mean that prescription is automatically bad.  It isn’t.  Sometimes, as shown above, it is both necessary and good.  It just isn’t good for describing how people use language, because a prescription can never be a description.  Each has its own purpose.

Comment: So would you say it is usually offensive to some groups? I agree that prescriptive grammars can be good and useful. I don't have any problem with them. My answer was itself prescriptive; I said how I thought they *should* write. I never meant the term pejoratively and wasn't trying to annoy people here. As a possibly interesting side note, I have heard that people actually correct only a tiny fraction of kids' mistakes, but I don't know what study/studies this information came from.

Comment: @Rachel No, I wouldn’t say that. However, if someone is purporting to engage in linguistic study, and if accused of prescribing usage rather than describing it, than I can see how they might take offence. On the other hand, you don’t want a second-grade teacher producing Google N-Gram popularity contests for her charges.

Answer (score 4):

My advice is to banish *prescriptive* from your lexicon.

*Prescription* at one time was employed by linguists as a handy name for the activity and purposes of previous writers on language, distinguished from the activity and purpose the linguists themselves were pursuing—*description*. In my youth, a linguist participating in a discussion like this one would have acknowledged—indeed, would probably have taken some pains to point out—that he was moving from the *descriptive* side to the *prescriptive*.

However: when the *terms themselves* moved from the descriptive/linguistic to the prescriptive/practical side, they took on quite different meanings. Those who stood for a less rigid mode of writing, based on popular usage, identified their activity as *descriptive*, and derided those who stood for maintaining the standards of the "best" writers as *prescriptive*.

These are the meanings which now prevail, and it's futile for you and me to protest that that's not what the terms mean to *us*. When even linguists (who invented the distinction) regard *prescriptive* as a pejorative, it has ceased to be a useful term of art; it's merely a party label, employed by Demoticrats to excite prejudice against Aristarchs.

It's a blunt tool; pitch it in the recycle bin and get a new one.

Comment: do you have any suggestions? I find the two existing ones very ... um ... descriptive.

Comment: I understand why you suggest abandoning the term, as it has become largely pejorative, but wouldn't a new term be simply shifting the problem to a new word? Maybe just have a continuum of descriptiveness.

Comment: This is advice, but I don't see an answer in here.

Comment: @RoaringFish  Sure, it *might* eventually shift the problem: express euphemisms tend accrete the prejudice they seek to avoid because they mask the problem. The trick is to get the people who practice prescriptive linguistics--for instance, the majority of people on this site, including you and me--to unite around the meaning of whatever term you come up with, so they can wave the label as a flag.

Comment: @Mitch: 1) I'll work on that (but not right away), along the lines of my answer to RoaringFish  2) I'll  edit to make clear where my answer to Rachel's specific question lies.

Comment: This explanation helps clarify things, and I guess it is helpful if it's the answer, disappointing though I find it. :^) My next question is of course what I can use instead if I can't use `prescriptive` without offense, but maybe that is for another question. Maybe that question would be good in meta?

Comment: @Rachel  My gut feel is that it's not a meta question, but I haven't been around very long. Maybe a new question, referring to this one but asking what to call an informed writer on questions of usage whose purpose is not merely to describe usage but to guide  people towards effective (not correct! or proper!) usage?

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries are unlikely to provide that information, as you are referring to something that is contextual.

*[“Much of the time, though not always, decisions about what is good and bad are essentially arbitrary and do not often reflect any crucial principle of language or thought.”](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=TbI8AdapFNAC&pg=PA1&lpg=PA1&dq=%E2%80%9CMuch+of+the+time,+though+not+always,+decisions+about+what+is+good+and+bad+are+essentially+arbitrary+and+do+not+often+reflect+any+crucial+principle+of+language+or+thought.%E2%80%9D&source=bl&ots=vBINqNEb3d&sig=BaBjNCma-WtFbZdXU772H2q0-yk&hl=en#v=onepage&q=%E2%80%9CMuch%20of%20the%20time%2C%20though%20not%20always%2C%20decisions%20about%20what%20is%20good%20and%20bad%20are%20essentially%20arbitrary%20and%20do%20not%20often%20reflect%20any%20crucial%20principle%20of%20language%20or%20thought.%E2%80%9D&f=false) and more.

*["Many of these rules were actually invented by someone.](http://emedia.leeward.hawaii.edu/hurley/Ling102web/mod1_popideas/mod1.8_descvsprescrip.htm) During the 17th and 18th centuries, scholars became preoccupied with the art, ideas, and language of ancient Greece and Rome. The classical period was regarded as a golden age and Latin as the perfect language. The notion that Latin was somehow better or purer than contemporary languages was strengthened by the fact that Latin was by then strictly a written language and had long ceased to undergo the changes natural to spoken language. For many writers of the 17th and 18th centuries, the rules of Latin became, whenever remotely feasible, the rules of English.

It is somewhat surprising that rules that do not reflect actual language use should survive."

*["Linguists tend to view prescriptive grammars as having little justification beyond their authors' aesthetic tastes"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammar)

*[...prescriptive rules are,  at  best,  inconsequential  little decorations.](http://pinker.wjh.harvard.edu/articles/media/1994_01_24_thenewrepublic.html)    The  very fact that they have to be drilled shows that they are alien to the natural workings of the language system.  One can choose to obsess over  prescriptive  rules, but they have no more to do with human language than the criteria for judging cats at a cat show have to do with mammalian biology.

*Confirming simchona's comment:
["Moreover, in order to obviate the messiness of exceptions, pedagogic grammars tend to be more assertive than they need to be](http://scottthornbury.wordpress.com/tag/prescriptive-grammar/) – often at the cost of accuracy. Rather than stating rules, they issue edicts.   (Perhaps they should be called ‘pedantic grammars’)."

I could go on forever with examples of why 'prescriptive' is a considered bad word in the language community, equating pretty much to pedantic or uneducated, with an implication of an uneducated little man (probably a schoolmaster), devoid of understanding, parroting something he read in a book. This may have been true 100 years ago, but believe me - we have moved on. Nobody wants that 'prescriptive' label.

Comment: Dictionaries do provide information on even *contextually* offensive usage. I didn't see any clear notes at dictionary.com, but [negro @ Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/negro) and [negro @ COED](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/Negro?q=negro) both note contexts where it is offensive.

Comment: That has more to do with politically correct offensive usage. Your COED mentions nothing about bitch being offensive, but would you agree that it can be when applied to a woman?

Comment: Okay, I understand now how it has come to have a pejorative sense even beyond what I was already aware of. However, I want to know if it has **failed to have the nonpejorative sense**. I think that my intended usage was perfectly accurate and acceptable. I mean it to describe a grammar book that tells people what they should do and does not necessarily reflect actual usage. I think kind of book does still exist. If I can't use `prescriptive`, then what is another option?

Comment: 1) [Wiktionary does list that sense.](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bitch) 2) [COED says "informal: a spiteful or unpleasant woman".](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bitch?q=bitch) Perhaps they thought it was redundant to call that offensive? 3) I wouldn't expect a dictionary to list all offensive uses, especially if they exist only in a small community and are in a sense technical. I checked them to see what they said and to be thorough.

Comment: No, I wouldn't expect a dictionary to list offensive usage, which is what I said in the first place. I would expect it to list non-PC usage though, for PC reasons. You say you are a linguistics student. Have you covered meaning? If so, I would expect you to understand that words have socially generated meanings beyond the lemma listed in a dictionary. As your COED says, bitch is not offensive to black women, but you agree that it is to most women. BTW... surely you have access to OED online? I am not a huge fan of dictionaries, but OED is the best one around.

Comment: I find your question insulting. Of course I know dictionaries don't cover everything. *That is exactly why I asked the question here.* Dictionaries *do* list offensive language (negro @ COED specifically says "offensive"); they just don't cover *every* case that exists. That they don't list `prescriptive` as offensive just means that they omitted the meaning that several people here obviously attach to it even when told by the speaker not to take it that way. Yes, I have access to OED but didn't check it or post a link to it here because I presume not every reader here does.

Comment: If you understand that, then it entails that you understand why ploughing through dictionaries is a pointless exercise... I have OED. Feel free to post links.

Comment: It would not be pointless if the dictionary *did* note an offensive usage. That is evidence that the word can be offensive. Agreed? I didn't know what I would find before I looked, so I looked. Not finding a note of offense in any of several dictionaries is non-conclusive but is still suggestive. It suggests to me that if any offensive usage exists, it is confined to within a small community or very special circumstances or is very new.

Comment: Didn't you just say you understood socially generated meeting? Claim to be insulted, even? Yes, obviously, the only people who would be offended by your comments about prescriptive grammarians would be non-prescriptive grammarians. Which is most of them, as my links show.

Comment: Okay, but my original post said "English prescriptive grammar books". You were the one who introduced "grammarians" into the discourse. I don't use that word myself because I don't know who exactly it even applies to now. And there are still plenty of prescriptive grammar books around.

Comment: Regarding OED, will my links work for others? They go through my school's domain. Also, if you have it, why not look it up yourself? Anyway, [prescriptivist](http://www.oed.com.resources.library.brandeis.edu/view/Entry/150655) says nothing about offensiveness nor does [prescriptive](http://www.oed.com.resources.library.brandeis.edu/view/Entry/150653), which notes "In Linguistics, opposed to descriptive (see descriptive adj. 3b).". The definitions are the ones you'd expect. `Bitch` notes "Not now in decent use".

Comment: No I didn't. Go back and check - it was you saying something about descriptive grammarians agreeing with your double full-stops notion. Sure, there are prescriptive grammar books. Your mistake is assuming the people who write them are prescriptive grammarians. They are not. They are people with a lot of knowledge of how language works, but understand that many learners just want to know what rather than why.

Comment: Your OED links would work for those with access, yes. Unfortunately, your links redirect to a university log-in page.

Comment: I apologize; I did introduce `grammarians`. I actually rarely use this. However, I used the phrase `prescriptive grmmarians` *after* you had commented and called my speech derogatory. For OED, I had to email myself to get [a different link](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/150655?p=emailA8d2VtLyZQXY.&d=150655). You can surely look up the other entries; they are linked to on the right.

Comment: I already checked OED; I was meaning for future use! I didn't make that clear - sorry. Mainly because there are very few online freebie dictionaries that I really trust. Thanks for emailing yourself though... interesting work-around. Have you looked at 'prescriptivism', specifically the examples: "The charge of prescriptivism is also made against Chomsky." and "Prescriptivism is wrong, the reader is told again."